# How to hide thumbnails when display size is reduced, instead of showing them below each other

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, media-queries

I am using thumbnail which are getting arranged as stack when display size is reduced. I want to hide them (overflow) when the display size is reduced.

Here is [Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/zL0tmqcm/5/) JSFIDDLE.

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">          
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <img src="http://marccortez.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/reading-small1.jpg" alt="...">
                    <div class="caption">
                        <h3>Thumbnail label</h3>
                        <p>...</p>
                        <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Button</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Button</a></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <img src="http://marccortez.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/reading-small1.jpg" alt="...">
                    <div class="caption">
                        <h3>Thumbnail label</h3>
                        <p>...</p>
                        <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Button</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Button</a></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <img src="http://marccortez.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/reading-small1.jpg" alt="...">
                    <div class="caption">
                        <h3>Thumbnail label</h3>
                        <p>...</p>
                        <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Button</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Button</a></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>  
</div>
```

Comment: what do you want to hide? only image or label

Comment: @SwapnilMotewar i want to hide whole div. When i decrease the size of display those thumbnails(div) get arranged below each other. I want to hide them instead of making stack of div.

Comment: so add hidden class to that div which want you to hide

Answer (score 1):

[image]You can use hidden-* to hide content on xs so added `hidden-xs`

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/swapnilmotewar/zL0tmqcm/6/